# MAMP not processing PHP after reinstall MAC OS

Tags: php, macos, apache, installation, mamp

Someone posted this:
[MAMP not processing PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819121/mamp-not-processing-php)
just a couple of days ago.

My issue is very similar.

In February of 2014, I did a manual install of MAMP.
The discussion from the above post is very familiar to me.

I reinstalled my OS this morning over the internet.
Now my PHP scripts will not process; they just return as text. For example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHdMP.jpg

Did this OS (re)install over-write my MAMP configuration ?

My .html files do launch, for example:

```
http://localhost:8383/exampleProjectName.html
```

comes up in the URL - localhost:8383 although in the past the :8383 did not exist in the path.  I believe I was running localhost on port 80

Because my .html runs on localhost, I do not think that I need to reinstall MAMP.
Do I just need to get back into the httpd.conf files and a few other files to uncomment// and add a few lines of code.

Is this correct ?

Comment: If you reinstalled the OS, you will need to reconfigure MAMP. Here's instructions on [Installing Apache, PHP, and MySQL on Mac OS X](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x/).

Comment: @JasonMcCreary thank you Jason.  i will do it !  followup question. I want to install wordpress.org locally.  Do you have instructions for this ? Most of what is out there references the one-click MAMP install so that there is a GUI and then they follow with the localhost wordpress.org setup. The other option, since I will have to reconfigure MAMP anyway is to do that one-click MAMP install and wordpress.org. If I do that, will I have problems getting my php scripts to run ? What will happen to my tables in mysql database. Sorry about my confusion.